# What is swarminject used for?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I can see that in all the tests of Jquery UI components there is include of swarminject.js file:

```
<script src="../swarminject.js"></script>
```

What exactly it doing?

Comment: Yes , but found only results of include likns that using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TestSwarm provides distributed continuous integration testing for JavaScript. It was originally created by John Resig as a basic tool to support unit testing of the jQuery JavaScript library. It was later moved to become an official Mozilla Labs and has since moved again to become a jQuery project.
>   The primary goal of TestSwarm is to take the complicated, and time-consuming, process of running JavaScript test suites in multiple browsers and to grossly simplify it. It achieves this goal by providing all the tools necessary for creating a continuous integration workflow for your JavaScript project.

source: https://github.com/jquery/testswarm/wiki